# How to set an array entry in the lowest level of a complicated array in a loop?

Tags: php, arrays, loops

Ok, I admit the question is confusing but I don't know how to say it in another way. I have an array that looks like this:

```
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  array(1) {
    [some_middle-level_id]=>
    array(1) {
      [some_low-level_id]=>
      array(5) {
        ["entry1"]=>
        string(...) "..."
        ["entry2"]=>
        string(...) ""
        ...
      }
    }
  }  
  [1]=>
  array(1) {
    [another_middle-level_id]=>
    array(5) {
      [another_low_level_id]=>
      array(5) {
        ["entry1"]=>
        string(...) "..."
        ["entry2"]=>
        string(...) ""
        ...
      }
    }
  }
  [2]=>
  array(1) {
    [another_middle-level_id]=>
    array(5) {
      [another_low_level_id]=>
      array(5) {
        ["entry1"]=>
        string(...) "..."
        ["entry2"]=>
        string(...) ""
        ...
      }
      [another_low_level_id]=>
      array(5) {
        ["entry1"]=>
        string(...) "..."
        ["entry2"]=>
        string(...) ""
        ...
      }
    }
  }
```

EDIT:
The other array would look like this. Let's say there are 3 [low_level_id] in the first array then the other array would simply look like this:

```
array(3) { [0]=> string(3) "bla" [1]=> string(4) "blub" [2]=> string(6) "lalala"}
```

and another array that have as many entries as "low level id"-entries exist. In every "low level id"-entry which contains 5 entries at the moment I want to add a sixth entry - a string from the other array. But I don't know how to access it. Is there away to access it without using hundreds of loops?

Another EDIT:
I could access the first entry with:

```
foreach($my_array as $key => $subkey){
    foreach($subkey as $val){
         $my_array[$key][key($subkey)][key($val)]['6th_entry']="a new string";
    }
}
```

But that works only for the first new entry. I don't know how to access the others and how to add a loop for adding entries from the other array.

Comment: You have to show content of "another array" too.

Comment: Alright, there it is :)

Comment: what about array[key][sub_key][sub_sub_key], etc...?

Comment: Hey Andrew - but how to get those keys and combine with a loop through to the other array to add the entries of it? Pls have a look at my edit - where to add the entries of the second arrow and what to use instead of key() to get not only the first key?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use nested calls of `array_map`. Assuming `$array` is 1st array and `$another_array` is 2nd array, the code should look like this:

```
$result = array_map(
    function ($elem1) use(&$another_array) {
        return array_map(
            function ($elem2) use(&$another_array) {
                return array_map(
                    function ($elem3) use(&$another_array) {
                        list(, $val) = each($another_array);
                        $elem3['entry6'] = $val;
                        return $elem3;
                    },
                    $elem2
                );
            },
            $elem1
        );
    },
    $array
);
```

[Demo](http://ideone.com/9fFNBF)

Comment: thx. But after replacing $arr with my first array's name and $another_array with my second array's name I tried it and following error occured: "array_map() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback" and I don't know how to replace $subarray. But I will check out php manuals about array_map and use

Comment: Sorry. I've confused order of `array_map` args. Fixed

Comment: Thx again but I think it's not doing what it's expected to do. Or I did something wrong but I just replaced the Variables: $result = array_map(
    function ($pdf_videos) use($titles) {
        return array_map(function ($subarr) use($titles) {
            return $subarr['title'] = each($titles);
        }, $pdf_videos);
    },
    $pdf_videos
); - that just returned an array of 3 with id's and the same title in every array but it added nothing to the original array. It deleted most of the entries and produced a new array I couldn't need ;)

Comment: Oo - it's even more confusing this time... I replaced the two $elem1 with the name of my first array and all $another_array with the name of my second array but " array_map(): Argument #2 should be an array" occures but the second is an array (contains 9 Strings). And how to replace "$array" - with the first array, right? Otherwise it's undefined. Damn, thought there would be an easy php function to access all low level entries ...

Comment: Brilliant! Thanks for the example! I was confused about the syntax and used it wrong. But it really works. Thank you soo much! :) I only worked with loops before now I have to find out how to write such functions! Very useful!